# Laravel RAW query with IGNORE doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a project for travel agent where I need to insert date that support incomplete date. So there are 3 possible format:

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM-00
- YYYY-00-00

`00` means month or day is not set.

In my database (MariaDB v10.1.28) I can run this query and it sets the date as I wish:

`UPDATE IGNORE departure SET flight = "2019-00-00" WHERE id = "10"`

I use `IGNORE` to bypass strict mode in `config/database.php`. In Laravel, when I tried to run this [raw SQL query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries):

`DB::update(UPDATE IGNORE departure SET flight = ? WHERE id = ?', ['2019-00-00', '10']);`

said record will have its `departure` changed to `0000-00-00`. Is this a bug? There is a workaround to use 3 tinyInt but changing structure might mess everything else up.

Comment: try to pass date value directly in query and tried ? DB::update(UPDATE IGNORE departure SET tanggal_keberangkatan = "2019-00-00" WHERE id = ?', [ '10']);

Comment: What is your column name ? `flight`, `tanggal_keberangkatan` or `departure` ?

Comment: @Rajapandian it gives the exact same result, `0000-00-00`

Comment: @rap-2-h my bad, it's `flight`